# use Color Class in GWT

Tags: gwt

I want to use Color ,in my GWT client side ,

i want this kind of color

```
                 public static Color myColor = new Color( 152, 207, 204) ;
```

if i use this import

```
                    import java.awt.Color;
```

at Client side it gives me error:

```
             No source code is available for type java.awt.Color; did you forget to inherit a required module
```

How can i use RGB colors in GWT client side , by NOT using CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a simple RGB-to-String converter:

```
public final  class Helper {
    public static String RgbToHex(int r, int g, int b){
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append('#')
      .append(Integer.toHexString(r))
      .append(Integer.toHexString(g))
      .append(Integer.toHexString(b));
      return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
nameField.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor(Helper.RgbToHex(50, 100, 150));
```

**---Update---**

More complex way with controlling of negative value, great than 255, and 0-15 value.

```
  public static String RgbToHex(int r, int g, int b){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('#')
    .append(intTo2BytesStr(r))
    .append(intTo2BytesStr(g))
    .append(intTo2BytesStr(b));
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private static String intTo2BytesStr(int i) {
    return pad(Integer.toHexString(intTo2Bytes(i)));
  }

  private static int intTo2Bytes(int i){
    return (i < 0) ? 0 : (i > 255) ? 255 : i;
  }

  private static String pad(String str){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    if (sb.length()<2){
      sb.insert(0, '0');
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work well for R/G/B values below 16 decimal (10 hex) ... for example, (5, 10, 20) will result in a string that contains "#5a14" ... not what you want!

Comment: @Andy King You right. But here is some other problems: 1. Negative value of int. 2. Value > than 255.

Comment: @FFire - Sure, you can add checks for invalid values; I was just pointing out that **valid** values were not all handled correctly. (btw, I'd recommend that, if you're going to use a `StringBuilder`, you should pass the one object around among your helper routines, instead of creating four `StringBuilder` instances every time the `RgbToHex` method is invoked).

Answer (score 2):

You are using AWT class of `Color`.

```
GWT != Java .  //so gwt compiler wont compile the awt classes
```

Use this [ThirdParty Color Class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/GWTcolorclass.htm) instead.

Just copy that class into your `utility package` and use it on `client side`.

Comment: thanks , actually i am using it in CellTable with extended rows , So i was previously using this for making my columns color: td.style().trustedBackgroundColor("blue");  ::  Now its not taking anything except String , Any way i can give these RGB colors to my celltable Cell.

Comment: May be the method takes only w3c slandered colors ..here is the list  of standered colrs http://www.docsteve.com/DocSteve/TechNotes/color_test.html.

Comment: thanks , +1 for this list , it will be helpful , but ideally to have some way to put the RGB colors of my own

Comment: have you tried with the getHexValue() method in the class which i gave ??it will return the color code like "#000000"  then you can pass i think.

Answer (score 0):

You used awt api color here. but  GWT does not emulate this library. Refer:

- [JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more correct version of the `RgbToHex` method from the answer by FFire (this version will work correctly for r/g/b values less than 16):

```
public static String rgbToHex(final int r, final int g, final int b) {
  return "#" + (r < 16 ? "0" : "") + Integer.toHexString(r) + (g < 16 ? "0" : "") +
         Integer.toHexString(g) + (b < 16 ? "0" : "") + Integer.toHexString(b);
}
```

Of course, you can use a `StringBuilder` if you wish.