# In GWT, how can i convert a color from rgba to Hex by using .getBackgroundColor()?

Tags: gwt, colors, hex

I have a gwt log which is

```
GWT.log("color ="+colorWidget.getSelectionStyle().getBackgroundColor());
```

what i have is

```
String format with  [INFO] color = rgba(102, 0, 255, 0.506)
```

Does anybody can help me to convert this to Hex format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any JS solution or simply write your own method based on one the solutions you can find online. For example:

[Convert RGBA to HEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576092/convert-rgba-to-hex)

Comment: Hi, i do not think i can use JS in my GWT project. Also, what i have is a String  ,not a Color. How should i convert this string to hex ?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use a Java function to convert the RBG value to HEX. Unfortunately there is not GWT method that does this. A Helper method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15404307/2791703).